# Как правильно задавать Check для столбца в SQL Server с типом hh:mm-hh:mm?

Tags: sql, sql-server, время

Стек: MSSQL, работаю из MSSMS

Привет. Есть такая табличка.

| Неделя(FK) | День(FK) | Время(FK) | Группа(FK) | Предмет(FK) | Преподаватель(FK) | Кабинет(FK) | Тип_пары(FK) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Нижняя неделя | Понедельник | 8:00-9:30 | 27С | Вычислительная техника | Митин А.Н | 207 | пр1 |
| Нижняя неделя | Понедельник | 9:40-11:10 | 27С | История | Белогорская Л.В | 206А | лк |
| Нижняя неделя | Понедельник | 11:20-12:05 | 27С | ОБЕДЕННЫЙ ПЕРЕРЫВ | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Нижняя неделя | Понедельник | 11:20-12:50 | 27С | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| nvarchar(50) | nchar(15) | nvarchar(11) | nvarchar(15) | nvarchar(100) | nvarchar(40) | nvarchar(5) | nchar(10) |

Значения в столбце Время задаются по связи с такой таблицей:

| Время_ID(PK) | Номер_пары |
| --- | --- |
| 11:20-12:05 | 3 |
| 11:20-12:50 | 3 |
| 12:05-12:50 | 3 |
| 12:05-13:35 | 3 |
| 12:50-13:35 | 3 |
| 13:45-15:15 | 4 |
| 15:25-16:55 | 5 |
| 17:05-18:35 | 6 |
| 18:35-20:05 | 7 |
| 8:00-9:30 | 1 |
| 9:40-11:10 | 2 |
| nvarchar(11) | tinyint |

Так вот, пытаюсь задать ограничение на создание в столбце Время_ID записи типа hh:mm-hh:mm. Как мне правильно это сделать? Читал вот эту статью: https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/487774/,
боюсь браться и все себе и вузу поломать)
Вообще - хочется ограничить Время_ID записи до hh:mm-hh:mm, чтобы не получилось случайно, что занятие будет в 25 часу, или в 24:79 и пр)

Как мне кажется, тут достаточно простого check, но я лучше еще и вас послушаю)

Comment: Для хранения времени используйте колонки типа [time](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Таким образом невозможно будет задать неправильное время.

Comment: Создайте два поля с типом времени для границ диапазона. А нынешнее представление сделайте вычисляемым полем.

Comment: У меня в расписании есть прикол, что в унике официально есть обеденный перерыв. И вот если пара начинается в 11:20, то в 12:50 начинается обед объемом 45 минут до 13:35, соответственно бывает 5 видов комбинации, когда ставится обед, а когда новая пара. Мне дальше нужно будет формировать .xlsx файл на распечатку, тут уже будет проблематично с 2 столбцами работать и клеить их. Каждый год таблица расписания подвергается ручному TRUNCATE и пишется расписание по новой, как и время, когда то у нас оно было 8:30, теперь 8:00, при этом в том варианте не было обеденного перерыва(законного, как пара)

Comment: из всего написанного не ясно, в чем будет проблематичность при использовании вычисляемого поля